# How to make text stay inside a div box and continue on next line when it reaches the edge of div box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I'm making this flash card app, and I'm using Angular to let the user enter text in an input text box and the text displays on a flash card below it. The problem is that when the user types a lot, the text overflows moves past and outside the div box. Here is my code.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.note">

        <div class="box">
            <div class="note">{{ctrl.note}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    border: solid;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #ccc;
}
.note {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Can you include `css` for `.box` element at Question ?

Comment: Set a width in the .note CSS class. Also consider the word-wrap property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: @oortCloud you should make that an answer so they can accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

The input type="text" box is meant for single line text.
To get what you are looking for you need to use a `<textarea>` HTML tag.

[HTML textarea tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

You could write:

```
<textarea col="20" rows="5" ng-model="ctrl.note"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

As advised by Ted A.

Set a width in the .note CSS class so that your browser knows what "outside the box" means.

Also consider the [word-wrap property](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)